# React Big Calendar is not working with react16.2

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am working on `react-big-calendar`. I am getting this error while started working with react:

```
TypeError: _react.default.forwardRef is not a function
```

Comment: Are you working with last version of big calendar: v0.22.0?

Comment: big calendar version 0.221

Comment: Can you test it with newer react and react dom versions

Comment: thanks  react: "^16.4.0", this version is working fine